# how to combine two tables mysql in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have 2 MYSQL tables first table name Users and second table name images
[image]

I want to margin 2 tables in one by FOREIGN KEY id but some users doesn't have imageurl_id how can i display all of them like this .
and if there are no images i got empty image list

[image]

i tried this but it not working

```
 static async get() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      db.execute("SELECT * FROM users,images where users.id = image.imageurl_id ", [], (error, result) => {
        if (!error) resolve(result);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join/6188334#6188334

Comment: _"but some users doesn't have imageurl_id how can i display all of them"_ .. you're looking for a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Also, don't use comma delimited joins from 90s. Use `join` syntax and the `on` operator for how the data relates. `SELECT * FROM users as u left join images as i on u.id = i.imageurl_id`

Comment: i knew the left join but when i use it i got results depends on how many image by id i have ,,,, redundant results depends on images

Comment: What do you mean? What is wrong with the result if you run this query `SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN images where users.id = image.imageurl_id` ?